# Validar una imagen cargada con react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo que precarga una imagen:

```
onFileChange(e,file){
    var file = file || e.target.files[0],
        pattern = /imagen-*/,
        reader = new FileReader();

    if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
        alert('Formato inválido');
        return;
    }



    reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.setState({ 
            form:{
                ...this.state.form,
                imagen:reader.result,
                archivo:reader
            }
        }); 
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

En las lineas:

```
   if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
        alert('Formato inválido');
        return;
    }
```

Trato de validar que el archivo selecionado sea una imagen, pero cuando cargo un archivo(imagen) siempre entra al if me envia el mensaje="Formato invalido", y no pasa a completar la accion.

> Como debo de validar que el archivo seleccionado sea una imagen?

fracmento del JSX:

```
<label>

    <img src={this.state.form.imagen} className="loaded"/>
    <input 
       type="file" 
       accept="image/*" 
       name="imagen" 
       onChange={this.onFileChange} 
       ref="input" />
 </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var file = file || e.target.files[0],
        pattern = /^image/,
        reader = new FileReader();

    if (!pattern.test(file.type)) {
        alert('Formato inválido');
        return;
    }

    reader.onload = () => {
        conso.e.log(e)
        this.setState({ 
            form:{
                ...this.state.form,
                imagen:reader.result,
                archivo:reader
            }
        }); 
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```